# Conversion int to float in Jasper while using MSSQL as database

Tags: sql, sql-server, jasper-reports

I have some data  and i would like to make this data report appears as float while i set this data shown as integer/numeric. I currently using sql like this code
`CASE WHEN SUBSTRING (c.kode_hs,1,2) = '71' THEN CAST(c.brutto AS float) ELSE c.brutto END AS brutto,
CASE WHEN SUBSTRING (c.kode_hs,1,2) = '71' THEN CAST(c.netto AS float) ELSE c.netto END AS netto,`

while i use my query in MSSQL or SQL Server, it runs perfectly. But the problem is when i put it on jasper report. How could i do the other way to make this case happen to me? Thanks anyway

Comment: Try dividing the result of the cast by 1.0.

Comment: Also, if c.kode_hs is not 71, what type is it returning?  SQL can't return two types in one column.  So if the first value it returns is an integer, even if you try to force it to be a float, it will return an integer.

Comment: When it's not 71, it appears as numeric. I've tried that in SQL server and it works but when i put on jasper, it didn't go to the goal.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of after writing my comments is:

```
CONVERT(CASE WHEN SUBSTRING (c.kode_hs,1,2) = '71' THEN CAST(c.brutto AS float) ELSE c.brutto END, NVARCHAR) AS brutto,
CONVERT(CASE WHEN SUBSTRING (c.kode_hs,1,2) = '71' THEN CAST(c.netto AS float) ELSE c.netto END, NVARCHAR) AS netto,
```

This will return the values as strings, but will probably have the float/int appearance you require.

Alternatively, if you are using this data to populate a report, you could pass all the values back to the report as a float, and include a format field to the report too: 0 = integer, 1 = float.  I've had to do that before when using a single field to display different formatting types.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I already tried that, but unfortunately, it didn't work. It just also appear as integer (numeric) eventhough i change the setting of jasper to the default. Is there any other way to solve this? Thanks Stuart

Comment: Can you show the code you used that's returning the values as INTEGER?

Comment: Is SQL returning the result to Jasper as float/int and Jasper is converting it?  If you're providing the value to Jasper as a string, I can't think of any reason why it would convert it to an integer unless your definition for the place holder is integer type (I dont know Jasper so I can't give you a true reason, just an assumption)

Comment: For returning as INT is Jasper's setting. I put type `java.lang.Long` or `java.lang.Number` on (as long as it's numeric ones) so that can be happened. i didn't take it as a string because i need another format data in .csv which if i use string, it can't be calculated in .csv.